# When is "extern crate" required

Tags: rust

I'm still a beginner in Rust and I'm pretty confused with the use of extern crate. I've read that since Rust 2018 *extern crate* is not needed in most cases, but some project such as [dotenv](https://crates.io/crates/dotenv) still use it in their examples:

```
extern crate dotenv;

use dotenv::dotenv;
use std::env;
```

When is `extern crate` required ? In which cases it *must* be used ?

Comment: Look at the commit history and frequency of that project.

Comment: It's not necessary, if they are using the 2018 edition of Rust (which they are). But they do anyway,.